# WCF interoperability with callback contract

Tags: wcf, interop, wcf-callbacks

I need to implement a service that supports duplex communication with non WCF clients (python, Java, Ruby, etc.). However, none of the default bindings seem to support such a scenario (wsDualHttpBinding not really being interop: https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/wshttpdualbinding_a_non_interoperable_binding)

Is there a custom binding which would offer callback functionality for non WCF clients? Alternatively, I am considering using CORBA to achieve the same functionality but the ability to use WSDL to communicate the interface definitions would be lost.

Comment: Are you tied to using WCF, or is an alternative like ApacheMQ an option?

Comment: No, I am not tied to using WCF but liked the ease of exposing interfaces to clients - until I ran into the problem with duplex bindings. Will have a look at ApacheMQ.